# Create multiple object files from one source file using CPP flags

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I currently have a class defined in C++ which includes a C-preprocessor variable to switch on/off a certain feature:

**A.hh**

```
class A : public B {
  //...
#ifdef PPVAR
  int _i;
#endif

public: 
  A();
  //...
};
```

**A.cc**

```
A::A()
#ifdef PPVAR
  : B(1)
#else
  : B(2)
#endif
  {}
```

which affects the member variables and the initialization of the superclass. Currently I switch between the cases by including/excluding "-DPPVAR" in my c++ compiler flags. However, it would be much more desirable to have both implementations available *simultaneously*. 
I could in principle duplicate these source files (A_on.[hh,cc], A_off.[hh,cc]) but since they have so much in common this seems very inelegant. Because the flag influences the members and the constructor of the superclass I don't see an easy way of controlling this feature by simply introducing for instance a global variable `bool switchFeature = [T|F]` and using

```
if (switchFeature) {
  //...
} else {
 //...
}
```

everywwhere. If this were possible it would be my method of choice and I would love to hear your solution to this!

As an alternative (although doubling the number of classes) I thought maybe one could compile this source twice, once with "-DPPVAR" and once without and producing two object files A_on.o, A_off.o, but somehow I would still need to duplicate my header for this to work and would require more modifications in the rest of the code.

I'd appreciate any insight and hints on how I could tackle this problem

Comment: I don't see how you'd use this. You can't have two definitions for the same class in the same program (One Definition Rule). Why are you trying to give the same name to two different classes?

Comment: You can submerge your class into different namespaces using the same approach (`ifdef PPVAR`) although this is ugly

Comment: Even if it were possible, this is a route to unmaintainable code, see http://www.literateprogramming.com/ifdefs.pdf.

Comment: @AlexT You can even mangle the name with imaginative uses of macros.  Some of the winning entries at http://www.ioccc.org/ make good use of this, but I can't recommend it for anything else.

Comment: It looks like you have two different implementations of `B interface` - why don't you go "object oriented" way and hide this implementations behind some factory? You can also use CRTP here because you don't really need dynamic polimorphism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class `A` template from `int`.

```
template<int PPVAR_val = 1>
class A : public B {
  //number of members can also differ for partial specializations
  int _i;

public: 
  A();
  //...
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
template<int PPVAR_val>
A::A()
  : B(PPVAR_val)
  {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a child to A and add virtual methods if some code differ between A and its child

A.hh

```
class A : public class B {

// Common attributes and Functions
...

protected:
A(int ppvar) : B(ppvar) {}; // Not public
public:
A() : B(1) {};

virtual method(); // Method that differ between A and its Child
...
};

class A2 : public class A {
// Attributes only needed by A2
...
public:
A2() : A(2) {};

method(); // Say that A2 will use its own implementation of method
};
```

main.cc

```
int main(void)
{
bool PPVar = ...;
A    *a;
if (PPVar)
     a = new A();
else
     a = new A2();

a->method();
return (0);
}
```

An abstract class A with two child AOn and Aoff also.